# Neat way to write this trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

Sorry, I am very new to writing a Postgres Trigger.

I want to write a Postgre DB trigger which gets fired on an UPDATE
 operation to a table in Postgres.

My question is: am I writing this trigger and related function correctly?   I have tested this code and it does work but not sure its pretty or efficient.  Can it be improved?

When fired this trigger calls a function which deletes any data in the table older than 30 days.

Thanks for reading, I hope you can help?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expire_table() RETURNS trigger AS $expire_table$
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM object_store WHERE purged_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days';
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$expire_table$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER expire_table_trigger
  AFTER UPDATE ON object_store
EXECUTE PROCEDURE expire_table()();
```

Comment: I've changed the tsql tag to sql - T-Sql is used only in Sql Server and Sybase.

Comment: So if nobody does any updates in that table for 15 days, it'll contain 45 days of data? Seems like you need something *scheduled* somehow rather than doing it based on *unrelated* changes to the table data.

Comment: Something like [this question on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/43937/6381) would probably steer you in a better direction.

Comment: There will be tests run every 15 mins which will cause the UPDATE to fire.

Comment: I would still like to know if my trigger syntax looks good.

Comment: I am going to assume my trigger syntax above is good.